# How do I make my data safe to be displayed on a web page?

Tags: html, perl, parsing, text

We use a text based CRM system. This system we custom built and works fine for internal use. However we are now going to be going live on the internet. The problem we have now is that the web developers are telling us that our data files contain all kinds of none web safe characters and symbols. I am working on writing a Perl script to parse through the data and correct the problem. My problem is that I don't know what to look for. I can write the script but what should I be looking for and what should I change them too? Any suggestions, ideas and help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While I'm sure you will get some good suggestions from SO, couldn't the web developers in your own company give you much more specific and helpful answers about what is wrong with the data and why it is wrong?

Comment: You are correct and I asked them to give me that info, however do to the fact that they want to write the script and bill me more for it. They have not given me all the info we need to build the script ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consult the [OWASP Cheat Sheet on Cross Site Scripting Prevention](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). It boils down to:

- Being aware of the locations where you should not put untrusted data at all
- Being aware of the different ways in which data should be escaped in the different kinds of locations where you can put untrusted data
- Using whitelisting (escaping everything except specified safe characters) instead of blacklisting (only escaping specified unsafe characters)

(Read the entire document, though, rather than relying on this summary...)

Comment: look here too...http://www.google.com/support/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1111200#Safe1

But you need to remember, all web languages are different and some will deal with these characters, some wont. Figure out what languages, systems or w/e your backend is using and build your list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. They are proving to be very useful. I know that the site is being coded in PHP and Mysql, what other information do you think I should know before starting my script.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'm not sure about what you mean by "writing a Perl script to parse through the data and correct the problem". Do you intend to write a Perl script that escapes the data in the database? If that is the case, I would recommend against it - as far as I know, the usual way of doing escaping is to have the web application do it; in other words, you should do the escaping in the PHP code of the CMS.

Comment: Oh, I don't know much about PHP. What we are doing is providing our web programmers with csv files that contain all the information that we would like on our website, style numbers, descriptions, image names that sort of stuff, and we are being told that our data is no good, or that at least a lot of it has special characters, and extra spaces, line breaks and all kinds of "other stuff"  to quote the programmers. So I figured I would write a perl script to clean the files up before we sent it to the programmers. What do you suggest I do in this case?

Comment: I see. I think you should try to get the web programmers to be more specific about why the data causes problem for them. If it is because the CSV file is malformed (say, one of the values contains a comma or a line break, but the value is not quoted), you should [read about how to properly produce CSV files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or simply use some CSV library to generate the files, in order to make sure that the CSV reading itself will not cause problems for the web programmers. (Continues in the next comment.)

Comment: (Cont.) If, on the other hand, the web programmers can read the files, but the values themselves cause problems because they contain e.g. < or >, I'd say it's the web programmers' responsibility to fix their PHP code to escape the values properly - as mentioned, the presentation layer, not the database, is the right place for escaping. If that is somehow not an option, you must, for each field in the CSV file, find out in what context the values from that field will be used (HTML elements, HTML attributes, JavaScript code, etc.) and escape the values accordingly before producing the CSV file.

Comment: (Of course, if some of the values contain actual garbage that you do not want to show at all, then you can simply remove the garbage portion of the values - escaping is for data that you actually want to show. :-) )